# 2D Vector with 3 columns and undeclared number of rows

Tags: c++, declare, 2d-vector

How to declare a 2D Vector with following specifications:

1. Should have 3 columns (Ofcourse not actually but still)
2. Number of rows undeclared

Some suggest i should wrap an array inside a vector as below:

```
                typedef array <float, 3> Point
                vector <Point> 2DVector
```

But is there a way to use only vector to obtain the desired 2D Vector?

Comment: A vector of vectors? A vector containing a `struct`? Or do you mean you want to use only a single vector and no other data-structures or containers?

Comment: @Joachim. Yes vector of vector. Yes I want to use only vector.

Comment: So use a vector of vectors (although the array solution seems better to me). Are you having a particular problem with that?

Comment: @deepak09027 okay thanks, I'm just going to make sure i understand you correctly before i try post an answer, when you say it should have 3 columns do you mean it must only have 3 columns or would it be a solution if rows and columns could be of any length? (and you just use 3 columns) and would you be comfortable with using an `initializer_list` inside the vector?

Comment: @James. It should just "use" three columns. I do not have problem with initializer_list.

Comment: @juanchopanza. The reason I am not able to use array wrapped inside a vector is: I need to return that vector to a function and the compiler doesn't seem to understand what is "vector<array<float>>". It is throwing error. Do you know how should I return an array wrapped inside a vector?

Comment: -1 The question is missing important details, like the reason behind this question and the compiler errors. Please correct.

Answer (score 1):

> How to declare a 2D Vector with following specifications: `[...]`

A mix of `std::vector` and `std::array` is perfectly fine for the requirements:

```
using table = std::vector<std::array<float, 3>>;
table 2d_vector;
```

---

> But is there a way to use only vector to obtain the desired 2D Vector?

Here it is:

```
using table = std::vector<std::vector<float>>;
table 2d_vector;
```

You'll have to be sure to only add 3 `float`s to the inner vectors though.

---

> I need to return that vector to a function and the compiler doesn't seem to understand what is `vector<array<float>>`

Well, yes, of course it does not. `std::vector<std::array<float>>` does not name a type. You probably meant:

```
std::vector<std::array<float, 3>>;
//                          ^^^
```

Comment: I am writing "using namespace std" before declaring the function. Should there still be a problem?

Comment: @deepak09027, don't use `using namespace std`. Just prefix STL classes/functions/objects with `std::`.

Answer (score 1):

Using an `initializer_list` could look like this;

First `#include <initializer_list>`

```
std::vector<std::initializer_list<float>> vec{ {1,2,3} };
vec.push_back( {4,5,6} ); // add a row
```

Accessing each element could be done like;

```
for (auto list: vec){

    for(auto element: list){

        std::cout<< element << " "; // access each element

    }

    std::cout<<"\n";
}
```

Getting at an individual element with (x, y) coords;

```
// access first row (y coord = 0), second element (x coord = 1, also the column)
std::cout<< "vec[0].begin() + 1 = (addr:" << (vec[0].begin() + 1)
         << " - value: " << *(vec[0].begin() + 1) << ')';
```

All of that together would output;

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
vec[0].begin() + 1 = (addr:0x40a0d4 - value: 2)
```

---

A cleaner way could be done like this;

```
// using a variable type of initializer_list
std::initializer_list<float> row = {1,2,3};
std::vector<std::initializer_list<float>> vec{ row };

row = {4,5,6}; // change list

vec.push_back(row); // add rows
vec.push_back({7,8,9});

for (auto list: vec){

    for(auto value: list){

        std::cout<< value <<" ";

    }

    std::cout<<"\n";
}

//access without looping
const float *element = vec[0].begin(); 
// pointer to first row, first element (value: 1)

element+=3;
// point to second row, first element (value: 4)

std::cout<<"\nElement("<<*element<<")\n";

// access the same element with x,y coords = (0,1)
int x = 0, y = 1;
std::cout<<"\ncoord(0,1) = "<< *(vec[y].begin() + x) << "\n";
```

Would output;

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

Element(4)

coord(0,1) = 4
```

---

Problems i can think of with this (assuming it's of any worth) are that;
1) the data is initialized as constant `floats` and as far as i know you cannot change them.
and
2) if you change the `list` to equal `{0,1,2,3,4,5}` you now have more than 3 columns.

Comment: Thanx for the input. I don't want the data to be initialized as constant floats and later restriction of not be able to change them. But it was informative. Thanx.

Comment: No worries, if you ever need a constant 2d vector you might think of this :)